# Clonar filas en JQuery pero con diferente ID

Tags: jquery

¿Hay alguna manera de clonar en `JQuery` un elemento pero que dicho clon tenga una id diferente?

Es decir, yo tengo una tabla y cada casilla tiene su propia id, si yo quisiera añadir una fila nueva de aspecto similar pero que sus casillas tuvieran otra id, ¿eso es posible?

```
<table id="Tabla-Rutinas">
            <tr> <!-- Fila1 -->
                <td colspan="6" id="Casilla-1-1"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr> <!-- Fila2 -->
                <td id="Casilla-2-1">Nombre</td>
                <td id="Casilla-2-2">Herramienta</td>
                <td id="Casilla-2-3">Series</td>
                <td id="Casilla-2-4">Repeticiones</td>
                <td id="Casilla-2-5">Peso propuesto</td>
                <td id="Casilla-2-6">Peso final</td>
            </tr>
            <tr> <!-- Fila3 -->
                <td colspan="6" id="Casilla-3-1"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr> <!-- Fila4 -->
                <td id="Casilla-4-1"></td>
                <td id="Casilla-4-2"></td>
                <td id="Casilla-4-3"></td>
                <td id="Casilla-4-4"></td>
                <td id="Casilla-4-5"></td>
                <td id="Casilla-4-6"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Es decir, yo quiero que dicha tabla sea ampliable, y pongo una serie de botones en función de si quiero añadir nueva fila como la 3 (que es de una sola casilla) o nueva fila como la 4 (que es de 6 casillas).

Entonces, si yo quiero que al clicar un botón se añada una nueva fila 4, pero que el id de cada casilla sea, Casilla-5-1, Casilla5-2, Casilla-5-3, etc

¿Como se podría hacer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo puedes lograr creando los elementos y no clonandolos. Creando un select donde el usuario obtenga el tipo a agregar, ya sea de 1 columna o 6. Luego creas cada elemento en un for y si es una columna, entonces se le asigna el `colspan` para que tome el espacio como si fueran 6

```js
$("button").click(function(){
  var $tabla = $("#Tabla-Rutinas");
  // obtienes el total de callizas
  var totalCasillas = $tabla.find("tr").length;
  
  // obtenemos el tipo a crear
  var tipo = parseInt($("#tipo-callizas").val());
  
  // procedemos a crear los elementos en base al tipo
  var $tr = $("<tr></tr>");
  for(var i = 0;i < tipo;i++)
  {
    // creamos la columna o td
    var $td = $("<td>prueba texto</td>")
    // le asignamos su id
    .attr("id", "Casilla-"+totalCasillas+"-"+(i+1));
    $tr.append($td);
  }
  
  if(tipo == 1) {
    // modificamos el td para asignale el colspan
    $tr.find("td").attr("colspan",6);
  }
  
  $tabla.append($tr);

});
```

```css
tr td{
 background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Clonar filas</button>

<select id="tipo-callizas">
  <option value="1"> Crear con 1 fila</option>
  <option value="6"> Crear con multiples columnas</option>
 </select>

<table id="Tabla-Rutinas">
            <tr> <!-- Fila1 -->
                <td colspan="6" id="Casilla-1-1"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr> <!-- Fila2 -->
                <td id="Casilla-2-1">Nombre</td>
                <td id="Casilla-2-2">Herramienta</td>
                <td id="Casilla-2-3">Series</td>
                <td id="Casilla-2-4">Repeticiones</td>
                <td id="Casilla-2-5">Peso propuesto</td>
                <td id="Casilla-2-6">Peso final</td>
            </tr>
            <tr> <!-- Fila3 -->
                <td colspan="6" id="Casilla-3-1"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr> <!-- Fila4 -->
                <td id="Casilla-4-1"></td>
                <td id="Casilla-4-2"></td>
                <td id="Casilla-4-3"></td>
                <td id="Casilla-4-4"></td>
                <td id="Casilla-4-5"></td>
                <td id="Casilla-4-6"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

No lo hice clonadolo porque debido a que puede ser que los modelos en como quieres que se creen las nuevas casillas(3 y 4) no esten en ese orden o luego las cambies, por lo que habria que modificar tambien el codigo indicandole cuales hay que clonar.

Answer (score 1):

Una vez clonada la fila deberías recorrer las celdas cambiándole el atributo `id`:

```
$cela.attr('id', 'nuevoId');
```

Evidentemente el nuevo id debe calcularse a partir del número actual de filas de la tabla y del índice de la celda:

```js
$(function(){
  $('button').click(function(){
    // Cogemos el nº de fila a copiar del atributo data-row
    var fila = parseInt(this.dataset.row);
    // Clonamos la fila indicada
    var nuevaFila = $('#Tabla-Rutinas tr:nth-child(' + fila + ')').clone();
    // Calculamos el número de la nueva fila
    var numeroFila = $('#Tabla-Rutinas tr').length + 1;
    // Cambiamos el atributo id de cada celda
    nuevaFila.children().each(
      (i, e) => $(e).attr('id', 'Casilla-' + numeroFila + '-' + (i+1))
    );
    // Añadimos la nueva fila después de la última fila
    $('#Tabla-Rutinas tr:last').after(nuevaFila);
    console.log(nuevaFila[0].innerHTML);
  });  
});
```

```css
tr{
  height: 20px;
}
td{
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="Tabla-Rutinas">
    <tr> <!-- Fila1 -->
        <td colspan="6" id="Casilla-1-1"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr> <!-- Fila2 -->
        <td id="Casilla-2-1">Nombre</td>
        <td id="Casilla-2-2">Herramienta</td>
        <td id="Casilla-2-3">Series</td>
        <td id="Casilla-2-4">Repeticiones</td>
        <td id="Casilla-2-5">Peso propuesto</td>
        <td id="Casilla-2-6">Peso final</td>
    </tr>
    <tr> <!-- Fila3 -->
        <td colspan="6" id="Casilla-3-1"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr> <!-- Fila4 -->
        <td id="Casilla-4-1"></td>
        <td id="Casilla-4-2"></td>
        <td id="Casilla-4-3"></td>
        <td id="Casilla-4-4"></td>
        <td id="Casilla-4-5"></td>
        <td id="Casilla-4-6"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<button data-row="1">Copiar 1</button>
<button data-row="2">Copiar 2</button>
<button data-row="3">Copiar 3</button>
<button data-row="4">Copiar 4</button>
```