# Cómo agregar filas de forma dinámica en HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```js
function Agregarfila(){
    let op = $("#table").html();
    let fila = '<td>';
    $("#table").html(op+fila);
  }
```

```html
</head>
<body>
<h1>ORDENES DE PORDUCIONES</h1>
<table id="OP" border="1px solid black" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="">
<thead>
    <tr>
    <th>Plan/Real</th>
    <th>Modelo</th>
    <th>Lote</th>
    <th>Cant.</th>
    <th>PO</th>
    <th>IA</th> 
    <th>CHASIS</th>
    <th>ALTERNO.M</th>   
    <th>SEMIELABORADO</th>  
    <th>OP</th> 
    <th>ESTADO</th> 
    <th>VERSION.S</th>
    <th>MONTAJE</th>
    <th>EDITAR</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
  <tbody id="table">
    <tr>
        <td>LCD6</td>
        <td>91DR32X7000</td>    
        <td>L101</td>
        <td>5050</td>
        <td>242917</td>
        <td>1000953</td> 
        <td>Transición LANZAMIENTO</td>
        <td>V1</td>
        <td>4-651-IAMAITV00693</td>
        <td>OP-202398</td>
        <td>LIBERADO</td>
        <td>V1</td>
        <td>08-sep</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
        <td>LCD6</td>
        <td></td>   
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td> 
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>4-651-MEMGBTV00373</td>
        <td>OP-202399</td>
        <td>LIBERADO</td>
        <td>V1</td>
        <td></td>
        <td> </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<input type="button" onclick="Agregarfila()" value="Insertar Fila">
<script src="jquery-3.6.1.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Estoy tratando de hacer una tabla, pero no he encontrado la forma de hacer una función que inserte una fila completa, solo logro que se agregue una sola `<td>`.

La idea es hacer con un `for` o si hay alguna manera mas fácil, porque o sino, tengo que poner la cantidad de `<TD>` que tengo.

Se podrá crear una función que inserte la fila completa o la cantidad de encabezados?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: En esta comunidad encuentras muchos ejemplos para hacer lo que buscas. [este](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/171188/copiar-row-de-una-tabla-con-jquery), [este](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/128050/clonar-filas-en-jquery-pero-con-diferente-id) o [este](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/357496/como-copiar-una-filas-especifica-dinamicamente-con-js-o-jquery-a-otra-tabla-a-tr) sin mencionar otros tantos. Una buena búsqueda te arrojará los resulatdos que esperas obtener.

Comment: Te recomiendo hacer [el recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) por la comunidad para que la conozcas y de paso vas ganado reputación y medallas.

Comment: "DJ CREAZY" muchas gracias por la ayudad me a funcionado el ejemplo que me mandaste le tuve que hcer un para de modificacion pero me funciono de diez

Answer (score 0):

Como estas ocupando jQuery puedes ocupar la función append, la cual agrega un nuevo elemento al padre.

En tu caso el elemento padre es un tbody cuya id es "table" (recomendaría ser más semántico con los nombres)

Además voy a suponer que tienes un array de objetos con las filas a agregar (este array deberías haberlo colocado en tu pregunta)

Entonces para agregar una nueva fila haces lo siguiente:

```
for (let i of myArray) {
  $("#table").append(
  `<tr>
     <td>${i.Plan}</td>
     <td>${i.Modelo}</td>
     <td>${i.Lote}</td>
     //etc
  </tr>`)
}
```

Comment: Hola. Gracias por aportar. En primer lugar, sería importante que expliques con más detalle tu respuesta. [Hay unas pautas por aquí para lograrlo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Luego, lo que sugieres es justo lo que el OP no quiere. _La idea es hacer con un `for` o si hay alguna manera mas fácil, porque o sino, tengo que poner la cantidad de `<TD>` que tengo._